# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFile' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html5, api

Hola que tal estoy tratando un curso de html eh llegado a un punto en que no puedo avanzar por la siguiente razón estoy usando apifile para poder crear y leer archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego al hacer click en aceptar me tira el siguiente error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFile' of undefined**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo JavaScript es el siguiente

```
var ruta;
var espacio;
var zonadatos;
var lector;
function comenzar(){
  zonadatos = document.getElementById("zonadatos");
  var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
  boton.addEventListener("click",crear,false);

  //pedir permiso a nuestro navegador para acceder a nuestro disco duro
  navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(5*1024*1024,acceso); 
  //5megas
}

function acceso(){ //lanza un objeto filesystem
  //creacion de sistema de archivos
  window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, crearsis, 
  errores);
}

function crearsis(sistema){
  espacio = sistema.root; //sera la raiz de nuestro sistema de archivos
  ruta="";
  mostrar();
} 

function crear(){
      var nombre_archivo=document.getElementById("entrada").value;

      if(nombre_archivo!=""){
      nombre_archivo=ruta+nombre_archivo;
      espacio.getFile(nombre_archivo, {create:true, exclusive:false}, 
      mostrar,errores);
   }
 }

function mostrar(){
  document.getElementById("entrada");
  zonadatos.innerHTML="";
  espacio.getDirectory(ruta, null,leerdir,errores);
}

function leerdir(dir){
  lector=dir.createReader();
  leer();
}

 function leer(){
      lector.readEntries(function(archivos){
        if(archivos.length){
        listar(archivos);
      }
   },errores);  
 }

function listar(archivos){
   for(var i=0; i < archivos.length; i++){
       if(archivos[i].isFile){
        zonadatos.innerHTML+=archivos[i].name+"<br>";
       }else if(archivos[i].isDirectory){
          zonadatos.innerHTML+="<span 
       class='directorio'>"+archivos[i].name+"</span><br>";
       }
    }
 }
 function volver(){
        espacio.getDirectory(ruta,null,function(diractual){
        diractual.getParent(function(dirpadre){
        ruta=dirpadre.fullPath;
        mostrar();
      }, errores);
   },errores);
 }

 function errores(e){
     alert("ha habido un error" + e.code);
  }

   window.addEventListener("load", comenzar,false);
```

ya llevo un buen rato dándole vueltas quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar orientándome. gracias

Comment: Estás intentando usar el método sobre un *supuesto*  objeto llamado `espacio` que no existe en el contexto del método `crear`. Es evidente que necesitas organizar mejor tu código, por ejemplo dotándolo de un método para obtener el `espacio` o algo así. Realmente tú creas ese objeto en `crearsis`, pero tus métodos no se relacionan unos con otros de la forma adecuada.

Comment: tratare de ordenarlos

Answer (score 0):

la función crear, no sabe que es espacio. Como te dijo Vladimir, para crear, espacio es un null. Pues no está en el scope de la función.